# Aligning items within the navigation bar for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uinavigationbar, frame

I have a navigation bar that contains a custom view which has a name and photograph. The layout of this customview contains subviews which are aligned using anchors. I then tried to add a button that I wanted to show on the right side of the navigation bar, so I added it like this, and the reason why I added it like this rather than the tradition way is because my image was being stretched if I used it as a background image in the traditional sense:

```
        //Adding Unmatch Button
        let unmatchitem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "heartbreak")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unmatchTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = unmatchitem
```

But it shows up on my application like so:

[image]

As you can see the right bar button is located in the middle. Which it shouldn't be. The way I created my customview was with anchors and below are some of the anchors I had:

Anchors for Image

```
        profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Anchors for name label and titleview which contains a containerview which holds the label and image

```
        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

I am unsure what I can do to make this right button actually be on the right. Because before I added the right button my customview was perfectly centered, so I don't believe I need to change the constraints for that rather it has to do with my custom button, but there are no anchor properties that I could find so I am unsure how to align it to the right. Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
I believe the solution is adding the button to the custom view I made. It is starting to work using this code:

```
        //Adding Unmatch Button to titleview
        let unmatchButton = UIButton()
        unmatchButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "heartbreak")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        titleView.addSubview(unmatchButton)
        unmatchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //create size for the button
        unmatchButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        unmatchButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
//        Unmatch Button Constraints
        unmatchButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
//        unmatchButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        unmatchButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

One issue I am running into is, how can I anchor it to the right side of the navigation bar. Because if I anchor it to the left of the name it doesn't work because that container stretches based on name length, so I want it to permanently be in the same spot every-time by anchoring it to the right of my nav bar, but I don't know what I can anchor it to. I tried this:

```
        unmatchButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (navigationController?.navigationBar.rightAnchor)!).isActive = true
```

But I get the error that it can't do this because they have no anchor ancestors.

Comment: So you have a `navigationItem.titleView` as a custom `UIView`? Try using the debug view hierarchy to get a better understanding of how elements are laid out!

Comment: I take it you are hinting I should add it to my customview itself rather than as a rightbarbutton. I will try that :)